# How to automatically copy files in Subversion from the trunk to a special branch?

Tags: svn, hook

We have here the following situation:

- User start a commit (on the trunk).
- He adds special keywords in his commit message to signal, that this change should be automatically done on a branch.

What could be a good solution to implement that? I see the following options (but would like to here which one you think is best):

- Look at every commit in a background job, and start another commit to copy the relevant changes to the branch.
- Implement a post-commit-hook that triggers the change after the commit directly.

What is your opinion here? Are there other solutions available, that are even more adequate?

Comment: How exactly are you going to handle merge conflicts in the other branch?

Comment: Well, no answer here. I think there cannot be conflicts, because there is no parallel development. But will ask that the originator.

Comment: If some commits are merged and some are not, there will be conflicts, since a merged commit might modify code that has been created in a non-merged commit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. In Subversion, copy revision from some subtree to some existing subtree is merge (-c, "cherry-pick merge" in case of single revision)
2. Merge can be performed only in Working Copy

Conditions of pp. 1 and 2 give us preliminary recipe:

Post-commit hook must:

- detect commit, which require action (otherwise do nothing)
- cd to local (for server) WC
- perform `svn merge -c... URL-OF-TRUNK`, probably, for auto-resolving conflicts, use `--accept` option
- commit to branch

---

Addition from @mliebelt:

- Best solution should be, to implement the script to automate that task, but run that script manually on the client.
- A config manager (or another knowable user) should then manually clarify the conflicts that may happen, in the best case, he has just to commit the changes with an appropriate log message.

Comment: Thank's a lot, that shows why a server solution may be inappropriate. Wait a little bit for some more feedback ...

Comment: I hope it is ok to add how a good solution could work, you are free to edit it again ;-)

Comment: @mliebelt - no-no... you'll use (want to) Integration Manager as monkey, it's bad style. Only merge **merges with conflicts** with user's intervention, don't replace bots by humans

Comment: I would have thought that my addition is clear: automate, what can be automated, but do it on the client desk, so manual invervention is possible. Do you know some implementation of a "merge automation tool"?

Comment: @mliebelt - client side **must be** informed only about *failed merges*. *Successful merges* **must be** executed without human intervention. "Merge automatin tool" is any CI tool, which allow creating custom task, isn't it?